# Escribir resultado de funcion en input text JavaScrip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo este problema chicos, necesito que el resultado de una función que estoy disparando con un evento se escriba dentro de un input tipo texto, en este caso el que esta luego de USD, consigo hacerlo en un elemnto `<span>` mas no dentro del `<input>`como quiero.

en fácil resumen, necesito que al ingresar un valor en BTC, el resultado que ahora mismo me da en `<span>`, me lo escriba dentro del `<input>` USD.

gracias de antemano.

```js
// BTC
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data){
     var btc = data[0].rank;
      document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = btc;
      btc = data[0].name;
      document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = btc;
      btc = data[0].price_usd;
      document.getElementById("btc-price1").innerHTML = btc;
      btc = data[0].price_btc;
      document.getElementById("btc-price2").innerHTML = btc;
      btc = data[0].percent_change_1h;
      document.getElementById("btc-1h").innerHTML = btc + " %";
      btc = data[0].percent_change_24h;
      document.getElementById("btc-24h").innerHTML = btc + " %";
      btc = data[0].percent_change_7d;
      document.getElementById("btc-7d").innerHTML = btc + " %";
    }
   });
  });
 });

// BTC Calc
 function multi(){
 var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
 var dato1=x[2].innerHTML;
    var total = dato1;
    var change= false;
    $(".monto").each(function(){
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
            change= true;
            total *= parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });
    total = (change)? total:0;
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

 <hr>

 <table class="table table-dark table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="coins">
    <thead>
     <!-- tittle tablet -->
      <tr>
        <th class="resp" scope="col">Rank</th>
        <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Price USD</th>
        <th scope="col">Price BTC</th>
        <th scope="col">1H</th>
        <th scope="col">24H</th>
        <th scope="col">7d</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <!-- btc -->
      <tr>
        <th scope="row" id="rank"></th>
        <td>BTC</td>
        <td id="btc"></td>
        <td id="btc-price1"></td>
        <td id="btc-price2"></td>
        <td id="btc-1h"></td>
        <td id="btc-24h"></td>
        <td id="btc-7d"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  
  <hr>
  
  
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">BTC</span>
      </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control monto"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1" onkeyup="multi();">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">USD</span>
      </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <p>Este resultado que quiero escribir en el input USD: </p>
    <span id="resultado"></span>
  </div>
  


</div>
```

Comment: te refieres a  `$("#input").val(btc);` ? o buscas otra cosa?

Comment: No entiendo porque no le pones un Id a ese input y asignarlo con $("#id").val(). No puedes asignarle un id?

Comment: Porque mezclas jQuery con javascript?

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez  , crei haberlo echo y no se por que razón nunca me dio. gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es facil, solo tienes que darle un id a tu input y luego usar .val() asi:

```js
// BTC
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data){
     var btc = data[0].rank;
      document.getElementById("rank").innerHTML = btc;
      btc = data[0].name;
      document.getElementById("btc").innerHTML = btc;
      btc = data[0].price_usd;
      document.getElementById("btc-price1").innerHTML = btc;
      btc = data[0].price_btc;
      document.getElementById("btc-price2").innerHTML = btc;
      btc = data[0].percent_change_1h;
      document.getElementById("btc-1h").innerHTML = btc + " %";
      btc = data[0].percent_change_24h;
      document.getElementById("btc-24h").innerHTML = btc + " %";
      btc = data[0].percent_change_7d;
      document.getElementById("btc-7d").innerHTML = btc + " %";
    }
   });
  });
 });

// BTC Calc
 function multi(){
 var x = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
 var dato1=x[2].innerHTML;
    var total = dato1;
    var change= false;
    $(".monto").each(function(){
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
            change= true;
            total *= parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });
    total = (change)? total:0;
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
    $("#usd").val(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

 <hr>

 <table class="table table-dark table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="coins">
    <thead>
     <!-- tittle tablet -->
      <tr>
        <th class="resp" scope="col">Rank</th>
        <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Price USD</th>
        <th scope="col">Price BTC</th>
        <th scope="col">1H</th>
        <th scope="col">24H</th>
        <th scope="col">7d</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <!-- btc -->
      <tr>
        <th scope="row" id="rank"></th>
        <td>BTC</td>
        <td id="btc">8</td>
        <td id="btc-price1">4</td>
        <td id="btc-price2"></td>
        <td id="btc-1h"></td>
        <td id="btc-24h"></td>
        <td id="btc-7d"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  
  <hr>
  
  
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">BTC</span>
      </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control monto"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1" onkeyup="multi();">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">USD</span>
      </div>
        <input id= "usd" type="text" class="form-control"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>  
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <p>Este resultado que quiero escribir en el input USD: </p>
    <span id="resultado"></span>
  </div>
  


</div>
```

Comment: si funciona perfecto, no se por que razón me mate la cabeza haciéndolo pero de alguna manera lo estaba haciendo mal que no me daba, me siento confundida, jajaja gracias!

Comment: De nada.  Una sugerencia, no es buena practica mezclar jQuery con javascript.  Si vas a usar jQuery, deberias usarlo para seleccionar elementos.  Por ejemplo: `$("#btc-7d").html(btc + " %");`

Comment: estupendo, gracias, estoy aprendiendo, agradecida.